# QML MouseArea propagate events to buttons

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm a developing an app that has a menu similar to the Gmail/Inbox app menu, for Android. Basically, when you press the button to open the menu, it slides into view. The user can swipe it away or press the buttons on the menu. For the swipe I've used the code `SwipeArea` from [kovrov](https://gist.github.com/kovrov/1742405) with a small change to check the speed between press and release - if it's too slow, I don't consider it a swipe. I've also set the propagate property to true on the `MouseArea`, i.e. `propagateComposedEvents: true` and added this code for the clicked event:

```
onClicked: {
    mouse.accepted = false;
}
```

Now I have the following code:

```
Button {
    x: 10
    y: 50
    width: 200
    onClicked: {
        console.log("Button clicked!");
    }
}
SwipeArea {
    anchors.fill: parent

    onMove: {
        var newX = menu.x + x;
        if(newX <= menu.maxX && newX >= menu.minX) menu.x = newX;
    }
    onSwipe: {
        if(direction === "left" && timePassed <= menu.fastSwipe) root.hideMenu(menu.x, timePassed);
        else {
            var middle = menu.width/2;
            var end = menu.x + menu.width;
            if(end > middle) root.showMenu(menu.x);
            else if(end <= middle) root.hideMenu(menu.x);
        }
    }
}
```

If the `Button` is rendered on top (code below `SwipeArea`) it works but then the swipe won't work on top of the `Button`.
If the `Button` is replaced with a `MouseArea` the event is correctly triggered. It seems the event is not being propagated? Is there a way to propagate the event to the Button? Or do I have to create my own buttons (`Rectangle` with `MouseArea`, for example)?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you're feeling brave, you could use the `SwipeView` that will be a part of Qt Quick Controls 2: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/111441/

Comment: Propagation occurs among `MouseArea`s, that's why controls such as `Button` does not receive the event. You can try to fill the `Button` with a `MouseArea` and `connect` its events to `Button` click or simply use a custom button, as you proposed at the end of the question. Or, if you are brave enough, you can try to  follow @Mitch advice and give a go to the new `SwipeView`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I've decided to go with the creation of my own buttons as it seemed easier. Although now I've run into a different, weird problem, unrelated to this question. So I've posed it in a different thread.