# QML Text having strange behavior? Text not appearing and crashing app

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm encountering a strange behavior with `Text` in QML. Which I admit is probably my fault, but I can not figure out what's wrong. I am creating a swipe menu like the ones used on the Gmail/Inbox app for android. As it was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578007/qml-mousearea-propagate-events-to-buttons) I found that the best way to have the swipe menu with buttons inside was to create my own buttons, so I have the following code:

`MenuButton`:

```
Item {
    id: root

    property string text: ""
    signal clicked()

    width: 100
    height: 62

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: parent.text
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked: {
            parent.clicked();
        }
    }
}
```

My `SliderMenu` is as follows:

```
Item {
    id: root

    function showMenu(startX, duration) {
        //Start animation to show menu.
    }

    function hideMenu(startX, duration) {
        //Start animation to hide menu.
    }

    clip: true
    visible: false
    Item {
        id: menu

        //shadow adds 1 pixel
        property int maxX: -1
        property int minX: -width - 1
        //Arbitrary number for what is considered fast
        property int fastSwipe: 200

        y: -1
        width: 250
        height: parent.height + 1
        visible: false

        Rectangle {
            id: rectMenu
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "#ececec"
            visible: false
        }

        DropShadow {
            id: menuShadow
            anchors.fill: rectMenu
            horizontalOffset: 1
            verticalOffset: 0
            radius: 4
            samples: radius * 2
            spread: 0
            color: "#80000000"
            source: rectMenu
            transparentBorder: true
        }

        MenuButton {
            x: 10
            y: 20
            text: "Text"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("I'm here!");
            }
        }

        SwipeArea {
            //Swipe area code
        }

        NumberAnimation {
            //Code of the sliding in animation
        }

        NumberAnimation {
            //Code for the sliding out animation
        }
    }
}
```

The slider is opened by clicking on the `TopMenu`'s `Button`:

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    height: 50
    color: "#4285f4"
    border.width: 0
    border.color: "#00000000"

    property SliderMenu slider

    ToolButton {
        id: slideButton
        x: 5
        y: 7
        width: 36
        height: 36
        iconSource: "../../resources/MainMenu/slide_menu_icon.png"
        onClicked: {
            slider.showMenu();
        }
    }
}
```

Which is like this on main:

```
Item {
    anchors.fill: parent
    z: 1

    TopMenu {
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: parent.width
        height: 50
        slider: sliderMenu
    }

    SliderMenu {
        id: sliderMenu
        x: 0
        y: 0
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

When I press the `TopMenu's Button` to slide the menu into view, 90% of the time (not always) the app will crash. If I remove the `Text` from the `MenuButton` it won't crash anymore. Also, I've tried adding a `Text` anywhere on the `SlideMenu` instead of the `MenuButton` and it gives the same result.

I've also tried to make the `Menu` always visible (so I won't have to press the `Button` for it to appear) and the app does not crash anymore but 90% of the time the `Text` is not there!
It only seems to crash if it is initially hidden and, if it doesn't crash at first, it won't anymore, even if I hide the menu and open again.

The crash gives a segmentation fault on Debug.

Anyone has any idea of what this might be?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: I was running this on windows because it is faster to test and I want it to also run on windows. I've just tested inside an android and it doesn't seem to be crashing. But I get this error on my console every time I open or close the menu:

```
Drawable.qml:70 ((null)): file:///data/data/org.qtproject.example.OSC_Client/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Android/drawables/Drawable.qml:70: TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'padding' of undefined

W/libOSC-Client.so(25977): file:///data/data/org.qtproject.example.OSC_Client/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Android/drawables/AnimationDrawable.qml:53 ((null)): file:///data/data/org.qtproject.example.OSC_Client/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Android/drawables/AnimationDrawable.qml:53:28:
Unable to assign [undefined] to bool
```

EDIT2: I've just managed to replicate this bug in a simpler manner. This seems to be related to the DropShadow on the rectangle. The simpler code is bellow. When I run it, 90% of the time the text does not appear. Tested on both MinGW and MSVC2012 on windows.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Button {
        x: 0
        y: 350
        text: "Show Rectangle"
        onClicked: rect.visible = true;
    }

    Item {
        id: rect
        x: -1
        y: -1
        width: 250
        height: 300
        visible: false

        Rectangle {
            id: rectMenu
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "#ececec"
            visible: false

        }

        DropShadow {
            id: menuShadow
            anchors.fill: rectMenu
            horizontalOffset: 1
            verticalOffset: 0
            radius: 4
            samples: radius * 2
            spread: 0
            color: "#80000000"
            source: rectMenu
            transparentBorder: true
        }

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Text"

        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the `DropShadow` it'll show the text normally.

qt.qpa.gl Log:

```
qt.qpa.gl: createPlatformOpenGLContext QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior 2, swapInterval 1, profile  0)
qt.qpa.gl: Qt: Using WGL and OpenGL from "opengl32.dll"
qt.qpa.gl: create OpenGL: "Intel","Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000" default ContextFormat: v3.1 profile: 0 options: QFlags(0x4),SampleBuffers, Extension-API present
Extensions: 116
qt.qpa.gl: "choosePixelFormat  Attributes:  0x2003 , 0x2027 , 0x2010 , 0x1 , 0x2001 , 0x1 , 0x2014 , 0x18 , 0x2011 , 0x1 , 0x2022 , 0x18 , 0x2013 , 0x202b , 0x201b , 0x8 , 0x2023 , 0x8 , 0x2041 , 0x0 , 
    obtained px # 4  of  1 
     PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR dwFlags=0x8225 PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL PFD_SUPPORT_COMPOSITION PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER iPixelType=0 cColorBits=32 cRedBits=8 cRedShift=16 cGreenBits=8 cGreenShift=8 cBlueBits=8 cBlueShift=0 cDepthBits=24 cStencilBits=8 iLayerType=0 cAlphaBits=8 cAlphaShift=24 cAccumBits=64 cAccumRedBits=16 cAccumGreenBits=16 cAccumBlueBits=16 cAccumAlphaBits=16"
qt.qpa.gl: createContext Creating context version 2 . 0 3 attributes
qt.qpa.gl: QWindowsGLContext 0x281246a0 ARB  requested:  QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior 2, swapInterval 1, profile  0) 
    obtained # 4 ARB QSurfaceFormat(version 3.1, options QFlags(0x4), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize 8, greenBufferSize 8, blueBufferSize 8, alphaBufferSize 8, stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior 2, swapInterval 1, profile  0) 
     PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR dwFlags=0x8225 PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL PFD_SUPPORT_COMPOSITION PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER iPixelType=0 cColorBits=32 cRedBits=8 cRedShift=16 cGreenBits=8 cGreenShift=8 cBlueBits=8 cBlueShift=0 cDepthBits=24 cStencilBits=8 iLayerType=0 cAlphaBits=8 cAlphaShift=24 cAccumBits=64 cAccumRedBits=16 cAccumGreenBits=16 cAccumBlueBits=16 cAccumAlphaBits=16 swap interval: 1
    default: ContextFormat: v3.1 profile: 0 options: QFlags(0x4)
    HGLRC=0x20000
```

Comment: Not without a stack trace. From the QML you've shown, there doesn't seem to be any cause for a segfault. Usually when there's a segfault from plain QML code, it's a bug in Qt.

Comment: I just found out that this is related to the DropShadow on the Rectangle. I've added a simple code on the question which creates this bug. Do you think this is a bug in Qt? I am using MinGW on windows btw. How would I get the stack trace from Qt Creator?

Comment: Which Qt version are you using? You need to enable QML debugging and then debug the application (F5) to get a stack trace.

Comment: I am using Qt 5.4. I do that but when it crashes the stack trace is basically: Level 0, Function ?? | Level 1, Function ??

Comment: Is that QML that you just updated the *whole* main.qml? If not, please post the entire thing, because it's not crashing for me on Windows with Qt 5.4.0 (MSVC2010). What happens when it crashes? Is there an assert?

Comment: I have edited with the whole main. This simpler code does not cause a crash (only when I have on my slidemenu and start the animation), but the text does not appear most of the time (sometimes it does). Also, if I run this code on debug mode and the text does not appear it crashes with segmentation fault. There is no assert. The selected "line" is assembly code on the "file" Disassembler (??)

Comment: It would be great if you could narrow down the code to the smallest possible example that reproduces the crash. Alternatively, build a debug build of Qt yourself so that you can get a stack trace. It might be the same root issue as [QTBUG-46411](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46411).

Comment: I think I found out what's causing the crash when I have the slide button. Basically it's when I set the item to visible. I've updated the question with the simplest code I managed to create to replicate this. Basically when I press the button if the text "was not rendered", it will crash the app.

Comment: Just tested it on Android again and I can not make it crash, although it prints those errors I added on my question.

Comment: Hmm, I still can't reproduce it. Is the build you're using an Angle build, or Desktop OpenGL?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (I didn't install it) OpenGL as the both MinGW and MSVC say OpenGL. Is there a way to confirm this, though? Could it be the Windows version? I am running on Windows 7.

Comment: Set the environment variable `QT_LOGGING_RULES` to `qt.qpa.gl=true` and check what's being loaded.

Comment: Yes, it is OpenGL. I've added the full log to the question.